# ftp_put(): Could not create file

Tags: php, laravel, ftp

I do not know what to do anymore I'm trying to overwrite a file from ftp with windows to a remote linux server using php.
I already tried with ftp_pasv in true, saying that I can not change the mode, I put this line in my file vsftpd.conf: pasv_promiscuous = YES and it does not work either.
Check the route in filezilla and it's the same.

Code php:

```
$ftp_server = 'ip';
$ftp_user_name = 'user';
$ftp_user_pass = 'pass';

$file = 'C:/archivos/sip_trunk.conf';
$remote_file = '/home/sk/sip_trunk.conf';

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Unable to connect to host");
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true) or die("Unable switch to passive mode");

$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass) or die("Authorization failed");

if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) {
 $text = "Upload $file\n";
} else {
 $text = "Error Upload $file\n";
}

ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Error ftp_pasv in false:

```
ftp_put(): Could not create file.
```

Arguments:

```
FTP Buffer resource @315
"/home/sk/sip_trunk.conf"
"C:/archivos/sip_trunk.conf"
1
```

Error ftp_pasv in true:

```
Unable switch to passive mode
```

I do not think it's because I'm running the code on a larvel controller

Comment: could it be a permission issue? Make sure the ftpuser can modify that file in that directory (not the authentication user but the actual user the ftp daemon is running under)

Comment: How can I see that?

Comment: well you could try `chmod 666 /home/sk/sip_trunk.conf` and if that fixes the problem then you know it's permissions related

Comment: okay, without wanting to winSCP I transferred the files as root, when I have to transfer them with the FTP user, 
It was really silly

Comment: @apokryfos Is there any way to leave the post closed without an answer?

Comment: Well, you could either delete it or answer it yourself in case other people find it useful. It's really up to you.